# « Correspondre », « aller », ou autre?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Je peux te renseigner sur les marques variées de produits de soins pour le visage que j’utilise, comme un exfoliant, un nettoyant et une crème hydratante.

> En revanche je ne pourrais te dire quelle marque

…**correspond** à un type de produit.

…**va avec** un type de produit.

> En revanche je ne pourrais te dire que telle marque

…**correspond** à tel produit.

…**va avec** tel produit.

Vous pouvez, si vous le souhaitez, me suggérer d’autres tournures. Merci.

Comment: Salut ! Que veux-tu dire ? Tu peux renseigner quelqu'un au sujet des marques des produits que tu utilises mais tu ne peux dire quelle marque correspond à un type de produit ? Souvent une marque a toute une gamme de produits...

Comment: Effectivement, mais sur le moment si on me demandait les produits que j’utilise je ne pourrais dire que telle marque correspond à tel produit, j’ai le nom des marques en tête sans pour autant pourvoir les associer à un type de produit de cosmétique, par exemple Maison lavande avec exfoliant,  C&W avec nettoyant et Nivea avec crème hydratante.

Comment: *pouvoir pour pourvoir…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> En revanche je ne pourrais pas te dire quelle marque correspond à quel produit.

me semble le plus naturel. J'ai bien écrit `quel` et pas `tel`.